# Encryption - Decryption with French Words in SQl Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, encryption

i want to add French word like `Catégories` in my table with `EncryptByKey`. Here is my query:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKey1
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate1;
insert into tbl_Name (Name)
values (EncryptByKey( Key_GUID('SymmetricKey1'), CONVERT(Nvarchar,'Catégories')))
```

but when i retrieve the value with following query, i got `慃㽴潧楲獥` instead of `Catégories`

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKey1
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate1;
SELECt CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),DECRYPTBYKEY(Name)) as Name from tbl_Name
```

Can you please give me help for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write French words along with a Prefix '`N`' to mark the string as Unicode and then encrypt:

```
insert into tbl_Name (Name)
values (EncryptByKey( Key_GUID('SymmetricKey1'), N'Catégories'))
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this problem is due to the **[collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144260%28SQL.90%29.aspx)** as data is stored in a UNICODE data type. I think you what you need is that when you SELECT the data, you want to ensure that an appropriate collation is used for the user who executed the request i.e. their locale.

You may try like this:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKey1
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate1;

insert into tbl_Name (Name)
values (EncryptByKey( Key_GUID('SymmetricKey1'), N'Catégories'))
```

The `N` will ensure that the data is stored as unicode format in database.